# Which is easier to deploy to a Windows server: a Rails app in JRuby or a Rails app in normal Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, jruby

We need to port a Rails application running on Linux to work on a client's Windows server. We've never done this and are unfamiliar with the Windows server environment. Our first decision is whether to try to port the app using JRuby or whether to just try to get the normal Ruby version working on a Windows server. Which course is more advisable?

Some gems we'll use that might be an issue (wildly guessing):

- nokogiri
- eventmachine
- em-websocket
- mysql or postgresql adapter

Comment: Could you add more information to the current running environment? Like special Gems used, the web server you use, ... I think it would be easiest, if the application with all the Gems will work in the new environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.
If you use a lot of gems with natives extensions try before the native Ruby, but I would suggest a port to JRuby because it simplify a lot the deployment on Windows.
I personally use only JRuby on Windows with JBoss and Warbler or with the trinidad gem.

And, it sounds strange, but JRuby scales very well and it's faster than MRI with Java 7.
I have several JRuby on Rails apps that use MSSQL Server or Oracle and they are awesome in production with only a few optimisations (http://http.tv4.se/2011/01/20/optimzing-jruby-rails-3-0-performance)

Answer (score 1):

From what I've heard, JRuby is supposed to be the best way to deploy Rails on Windows. But try to avoid this. Rails is happiest in a *nix environment, and anyway Windows is a terrible server OS.

If you can't get a *nix server, how about virtualizing?

Comment: From my experience virtualization is slow (I've tried Ubuntu on a Mac via VirtualBox). I'm a *nix guy all the way, but the client is a Windows shop with high security requirements (no cloud app).

Comment: I'm talking about a virtualization solution made specifically for servers (I'm not a sysadmin, but I know that such things exist -- things like Xen and some versions of VMWare). Presumably this is meant to deal with the performance issues.

Comment: Anyway, if the client has all these security requirements, he should be willing to bring a *nix server in-house if that's the best solution (which, in this case, it is). Not to mention that the idea of a high-security Windows shop is itself laughable.... :D

Comment: Sorry, I am with you personally, but we don't have that kind of leverage over the client.

Comment: Not every client is worth accommodating. :)

Comment: I hear you. :) But I'm actually kind of interested in learning what the Windows parallel universe is like.

Comment: Good luck. Running native with MRI is apparently very slow on Windows, but OTOH I don't know if Nokogiri has been ported to JRuby yet...